# Builder::whereBetween(): Argument #2 ($values) must be of type array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

```
 public function report($firstdate,$lastdate, $jenis_kas){
      
        $print = Wallets::select('*')->whereNotNull('uang_masuk')->whereBetween('tanggal','jenis_kas', [$firstdate, $lastdate,$jenis_kas])->latest()->get();
        return view('cetak/pemasukan',compact('print'));
    }
```

Comment: The whereBetween method verifies that a column's value is between two values. What do you want to get?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the equivalent SQL query you expect to get from that?

Comment: i want a print report filter by name and date @SNSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        $print = Wallets::select('*')->whereNotNull('uang_masuk')->where('jenis_kas', $jenis_kas)->whereBetween('tanggal', [$firstdate, $lastdate])->latest()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The whereBetween method verifies that a column's value is between two values:

It verifies a single column, you are using 2 columns

```
->whereBetween('tanggal','jenis_kas', [$firstdate, $lastdate,$jenis_kas])
```

change this to

```
->whereBetween('tanggal', [$firstdate, $lastdate,$jenis_kas])
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Comment: i want a using 2 column's value , because me have 2 values, i want print report filter by name. and date ..

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <a href="" onclick="this.href='/reports/pemasukan/'+document.getElementById('firstdate').value +'/'+document.getElementById('lastdate').value +'/'+ document.getElementById('jenis_kas').value" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary fa fa-print">Cetak</button>
        <a>
</div>
```